# Enable visible mouse cursor in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, mouse, cursor, nexus-7, peripherals

I am running a new nexus 7 with Ubuntu Touch (3.4.0-4) installed. I have plugged a mouse into the usb slot, and the device receives input (randomly clicking and dragging works) but the mouse cursor is invisible. Is there a way to make the cursor visible?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this yet? I'm also curious as I would like to use my MX4 with keyboard & mouse. Did you find out which service is responsible for mouse cursors?

Comment: @MaartenKlop unfortunately it seems that this is a known "bug"/lacking feature and is hopefully going to be resolved in a future release. There is no way to fix it as far as I found.

Comment: I couldn't find that it is known, but good to hear. Looking forward to this feature, would be useful! :D